# Converting JSON to different format

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a JSON of the format below

```
{
"results":
[
    {
        "position": {"Field1":11,"Filed2":12},
        "Field3":13,
        "Filed4":14,
        "Field5":15
    },

    {
        "position":{"Field1":21,"Filed2":22},
        "Field3":23,
        "Filed4":24,
        "Filed5":25
    }

]
}
```

Converting to below format

```
{
"results":
[
    {
        "Field1":11,
        "Filed2":12,
        "Field3":13,
        "Filed4":14,
        "Field5":15
    },

    {
        "Field1":21,
        "Filed2":22,
        "Field3":23,
        "Filed4":24,
        "Filed5":25
    }

]
}
```

I am trying below code Is there any better way to handle this

```
  for(int i = 0; i<resultsJSONArray.length(); ++i){ 
        if(resultsJSONArray.get(i).has("position")) {
              String names[] = JSONObject.getNames(resultsJSONArray.get(i).get("position")));
              for(int i = 0; i<names().length; ++i) {                                       
                  resultsJSONArray.get(i).put(names[i],resultsJSONArray.get(i).get("position").get(names[i]));
              }
              JSONObject.getNames(resultsJSONArray.get(i).remove("position"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it work? If not, what doesn't work?

Comment: My solution to this would be parse it to a Java object using GSON or Jackson.. then create the new Java Object according to the new layout .. and then reconvert it back to JSON..

Answer (score 0):

```
class SourceJSON{
// define data model for original json format
}

class DestJSON{
// define data model for required json format
}
```

// then finally you can convert your original source to data class, format it and write back to json format

```
   SourceJSON data = new Gson().fromJson(json, SourceJSON.class);
   DestJSON destdata = new DestJSON();
   destdata.setField(data.get(..));

   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(destdata);
```